# Jquery Remove then Add Class Twice on Hover (see details)

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass, removeclass

I am attempting to build a navigation bar for an HTML template.

The navigation bar has an arrow to the right of the links that have the class "drop". jQuery has a single line of code that, if it has the class "drop", then it uses `addClass` to add a background arrow that stays there when the link is not hovering. See code now:

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <a href="index.html" class="first">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html" class="drop">About Us</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="drop">Other</a>
    <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="http://forcefire.us/">Web Hosting</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="last">&nbsp;</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border-top: 1px solid #222;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}

nav a {
    padding: 15px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #888;
    font: bold 14px Sansation;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 -4px 0 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #444;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
}

nav a:hover {
    background: #444;
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 0%, rgb(85,85,85) 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 0%, rgb(85,85,85) 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 0%, rgb(85,85,85) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 0%, rgb(85,85,85) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 0%, rgb(85,85,85) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(68,68,68)), color-stop(1, rgb(85,85,85)));
}
    nav .drop {
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    nav .drop-d {
        background: url(../images/nad.png) no-repeat;
        background-position: 94% 50%;
    }
    nav .drop-u {
        background: url(../images/nau.png) no-repeat;
        background-position: 94% 50%;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Navigation Script
    $('nav .drop').addClass('drop-d');
    $('nav .drop').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).removeClass('drop-d').addClass('drop-u');
        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('drop-u').addClass('drop-d');
        }
    );
});
```

Now, the first line that only adds the class 'drop-d' shows the arrow. That's not the problem though.

The `.hover()` function removes the class 'drop-d', but it does not add the class 'drop-u' on hover. Off of hover (whether it remove the class 'drop-u' or not, I can't tell), but it once again adds the class 'drop-d'.

I'm sorry if it's obvious but it's late. Anyways, what's wrong and what's a better way to write it, besides permanently adding the class in CSS and then just removing that on hover and etc.?

Comment: seems to be fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6Gbg2/1/

Comment: Are you implementing the native CSS hover behavior with JS?

Comment: @ArunPJohny , the image nau.png isn't showing up. That's what I don't get.

Comment: @Itay, I am not. It's just changing classes that have different backgrounds. edit - I take that back, the anchor tags do have a background image that is a CSS gradient, but it wouldn't work even if I removed that.

Answer (score 0):

You're overdoing that. That's sounds like the native CSS [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover) behavior.

Use this CSS instead of your CSS + JS:

```
nav .drop {
    padding-right: 20px;
    background: url(../images/nad.png) 94% 50% no-repeat;
}
nav .drop:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/nau.png);
}
```

P.S - Notice you don't need to set the background's position in a separate row. You can write it as a part of the [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) setting.

---

As to the "nau.png" not showing issue.

You have the following class which is probably colliding with the other settings because they apply on the same elements.

```
nav a:hover {
    background: #444;
    background-image: linear-gradient ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks so far. Do you have an idea why the nau.png isn't showing up?

Comment: 1. Are you sure it's located on the same directory as `nad.png`?

Comment: Oh my goodness...... No, it's there. Sorry, I didn't direct that at you, but I just cleared my cache and it popped up. I check in the other browsers and it worked so I decided to clear chromes and bam, the image appeared.... I'm sorry for not doing that sooner

Comment: It happens. Anyway I suggest using the CSS way as shown in my answer instead of JS.